# Indexing an array with a tuple

Tags: multidimensional-array, python-3.x

Suppose I have a tuple of `(1, 2, 3)` and want to index a multidimensional array with it such as:

```
index = (1, 2, 3)
table[index] = 42 # behaves like table[1][2][3]
```

`index` has an unknown number of dimensions, so I can't do:

```
table[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]]
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], index, table)
```

but it's utterly ugly (and maybe also inefficient), so I wonder if there's a better, more Pythonic choice.

**EDIT:** Maybe a simple loop is best choice:

```
elem = table
for i in index:
    elem = elem[i]
```

**EDIT2:** Actually, there's a problem with both solutions: I can't assign a value to the indexed array :-(, back to ugly:

```
elem = table
for i in index[:-1]:
    elem = elem[i]
elem[index[-1]] = 42
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is very interesting and also your suggested solution looks good (havn't checked it, but this kind of problem requires a recursive treatment and you just did it in one line). 
However, the pythonic way I use in my programs is to use dictionaries of tuples. The syntax is array-like, the performance - of a dictionary, and there was no problem in it for me.

For example:

```
a = {(1, 2, 3): 'A', (3, 4, 5): 'B', (5, 6, 7, 8): 'C'}
print a[1, 2, 3]
print a[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Will output:

```
A
B
```

And assigning to an index is super easy:
`a[1, 4, 5] = 42`. (But you might want to first check that (1, 4, 5) is within the dict, or else it will be created by the assignment)

Comment: Clever solution! However, my array is actually a contiguous ctypes.c_float, can't use dictionaries there. Nice answer nonetheless.